# Can we search for a file in the client machine using applet?

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, applet

I am a PHP developer. I have a requirement that there will a particular file in the client machine and if this file exists then the user able to log in in the web site. I can get file existence by using the code given below:

```
import java.io.File;
class FileSearchFirstOrder{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean isExistP = false;
        File volumes = new File("/Volumes");
        File files[] = volumes.listFiles();
        for(File f: files)
        {
            //System.out.println("Current File -> " + f.getPath()); 
            isExistP = parseAllFiles(f.getPath());
            if(isExistP ==  true)
                break;
        }
        if(isExistP ==  true)
            System.out.println("I got the desire file Please continue.");
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry! I can not find the desire file Please try again leter:(");

    }

    public static boolean parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory)
    { 
        boolean isExistPC = false;
        try
        {
            File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles(); 
                for(File f : filesInDirectory)
            {  
                if (f.getName().toString().equals("key.txt"))
                {
                        //System.out.println("Current File ->" + f.getName()); 
                    isExistPC = true;
                }
                }  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
        return isExistPC;
    }  
}
```

but how can i implement this in my project and send this response to the server such that the end user can able to log in or not.

Comment: What ever the code you posted is applet?

Comment: this is not applet. This is simply java code. And I have to transfer this code to applet.

Answer (score 4):

The applet of my Question is in below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class AppletFileSearch extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
 private JPanel pane = null;
 public void init() 
 {
    try{
        jbInit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public boolean parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory)
{ 
    boolean isExistPC = false;
    try
    {
        File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles(); 
            for(File f : filesInDirectory)
        {  
            if (f.getName().toString().equals("key.txt"))
            {
                isExistPC = true;
            }
        }  
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return isExistPC;
}  
 private void jbInit() throws Exception
 {  
    boolean isExistP = false;
    File files[] = File.listRoots();
    for(File f: files)
    {
        isExistP = parseAllFiles(f.getPath());
        if(isExistP ==  true)
            break;
    }
    if(isExistP ==  true)
    {
    pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 35));
        pane.setLayout(null);
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
        pane.setBackground(new Color(0, 255,0));
        setContentPane(pane);
    }
    else
    {
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 35));
        pane.setLayout(null);
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
        pane.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        setContentPane(pane);
    }
 }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}
}
```

Now compile this source using
    **javac AppletFileSearch.java**
 in command prompt then make it jar file using the command
    **jar cvf AppletFileSearch.jar AppletFileSearch.class**
After that you have to make key certificate by using the command
    **keytool -genkey -alias AppletFileSearch -validity 365**
There will 10 or 11 steps (that will take password, first name, last name example is given in the url: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm).Again use the command for final signature 
    **jarsigner AppletFileSearch.jar AppletFileSearch**
There will be a prompt for asking password which you gave previous. If you give correct password the there will be a message the signer certificate will expire within six months.

After making this steps you have make a html page and the code will be like that:

```
<html>
<title>Run Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="AppletFileSearch.class" archive="AppletFileSearch.jar"
       width=325 height=325></applet>
</body>
</html
```

and save this html file as AppletFileSearch.html and keep both the files AppletFileSearch.html and AppletFileSearch.jar in the server(like apache). And run from the browser and lets enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to do what you need through an applet, more specifically, a [signed applet](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html). [This](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm) tutorial should point you in the right direction so that you can get your applet to access the local file system of the user.

Answer (score 0):

[Unsigned applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) access client resources such as the local filesystem, etc. In order to open that file you would need to deploy a signed applet (and I think the user is warned that the applet will run with unrestricted privileges).As an alternative approach, you could implement [TSL/SSL client authentication](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-SSL_client_authentication/) instead.